# p5.js Music VIsualization

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've created a sketch that has an array that draws circles to the amplitude of a song I've loaded within the code, for an iPad. I am now trying to modify those circles (ie. change the colors or add strokes at certain values of the amplitude with if then statements, however, I am not sure exactly where to place these if then statements. Everything I have tried has not affected the drawn visuals.

The key is to have the circles / visuals "draw" or do something even when your finger is not on the screen, in the last place you "touched". Also this sketch can be interacted with on mmengle.com as the startover_music link.

```
var circles = [];


function preload() {
  sound = loadSound('assets/findingnemoegg.mp3');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  amplitude = new p5.Amplitude();
  sound.play();

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {  
  circles[i] = {
    display: function() {
      var level = amplitude.getLevel();
      var size = map(level, 0, 1, 10, 900);
      noStroke();
      fill(128,166,206,40);
      ellipse(touchX + level, touchY + level, size, size);

  }
    }
  }

    }

function draw() {

  fill(255,8);
  rect(0,0,windowWidth, windowHeight);



  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].display();
  }

}
```

Comment: so you want a circle to be drawn at the last place the user touched, with a certain color?

Answer (score 0):

Im going to assume that this is what you want:

```js
var circles = [];
var lastTouchX;
var lastTouchY;

function preload() {
  sound = loadSound('assests/findingnemoegg.mp3');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  amplitude = new p5.Amplitude();
  sound.play();

  lastTouchX = width / 2;
  lastTouchY = height / 2;
}

function draw() {

  fill(255, 8);
  rect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].display();
  }

}

//change to touchEnded()
function mousePressed() {
  lastTouchX = mouseX;
  lastTouchY = mouseY;
  circles.push(new Circle());
}

function Circle() {
  this.x = lastTouchX;
  this.y = lastTouchY;

  this.display = function() {
    var level = amplitude.getLevel();
    var size = map(level, 0, 1, 10, 200);
    noStroke();
    //if statement to change fill
    fill(128, 166, 206, 40);
    //if statement to change fill
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, size, size);

  }
}
```

Comment: The only error I'm receiving is that width and height aren't defined! Otherwise it looks like it should work.

Comment: Yeah sorry `var lastTouchX; var lastTouchY;` and in setup `lastTouchX = width / 2; lastTouchY = height / 2;`

Comment: The circle only seems to stay in the center! And doesn't move based on mouse or touch interaction hmm..

Comment: Ok let me have a look at it, ill update my answer in a moment

Comment: you might also have to change `mousePressed()` to `touchEnded()` or `touchStarted()` to run on ipad

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the initial start / help, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, anything else i can help you with? You might also consider marking my answer as accepted, helps a lot. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Not a the moment! But I'll be continuously working on this, so I'll reach out when I get stuck again! Thanks!.